# Accessing list of registered factories/services in wired/pyramid_services

Tags: pyramid

I'm trying to debug my usage of wired and pyramid_services as well as migrate from using named services to registering services with interfaces and context classes.

Is there a way to see everything that is registered with the current container?  Both for **debugging** and also to **create fixtures for pytest during testing**.  Sort of like the `get_registrations` line of this pseudo code for injecting tests into `conftest.py` for pytests:

```py
def generate_service_fixture(reg):
    @pytest.fixture()
    def service_fixture(base_app_request):
        return base_app_request.find_service(iface=reg.iface, context=reg.context, name=reg.name)
    return service_fixture

def inject_service_fixture(reg):
    parts = [
        get_iface_name(reg.iface),
        get_context_name(reg.context),
        get_name(reg.name)]
    # Make up a name that tests can use to pull in the appropriate fixture.
    fixture_name = '__'.join(filter(None, parts)) + '_service'
    globals()[fixture_name] = generate_service_fixture(reg)

def get_iface_name(iface):
    return iface.__name__ if iface else None
def get_context_name(context):
    return context.__name__ if context else None
def get_name(name):
    return name if name else None
def register_fixtures(container):
    for reg in container.get_registrations():
        inject_service_fixture(reg)
```

Later on in tests I would do something like:

```py
def test_service_factory(IRequest_service):
    assert IRequest_service, "Factory failed to construct request."
```

Comment: I found out that I can use the introspector but it doesn't work as far as I can tell to dynamically create fixtures so I just did some hack-job.

Answer (score 0):

This sort of works for debugging after the services have been declared.  I'm just posting this half-answer for now.  I don't have a clean solution for dynamic pytest fixture creation.

```
def includeme(config):
    # ...
    config.commit()
    introspector = config.registry.introspector
    for intr in introspector.get_category('pyramid_services'):
       print (intr['introspectable'])
```